# RegExp help: How do I find a match for a character that has a particular character coming before it?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm actually trying to delete every space in a small function statement excepted if the word "function" or "return" comes before it. This is what I tried but to no avail:

```
function hi() {
    return "Hello";
}
hi.toString().replace(/\b\s+?=(return|function)/g, '');
```

Comment: use an existing javascript minifier ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no lookbehind in javascript regex, but this should do the trick:

```
hi.toString().replace(/(return|function)?\s/g, function(match) {
    if (match.length > 1) return match;
    else return '';
});
```

This matches single spaces, eventually preceeded by *function* or *return*.

If the match is a single character, we replace it by an empty string. Else, we do not replace it.

Try it here: http://jsfiddle.net/ebY5w/2/

Comment: No. I dont want to delete function and return. I just want to delete the spaces which don't have the word function or return preceding it.

Answer (score 2):

Well I have pretty funny solution.

```
// Helper method reverse
String.prototype.reverse = function() {
    return this.split('').reverse().join('');
};

hi.toString().reverse().replace(/(\s+(?!nruter|noitcnuf))/g, '').reverse();
```

In Javascript we can't use negative lookbehind, but we can reverse the string and use negative lookahead, and then reverse string back!
For your function it will give:

```
function hi(){return "Hello";}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the [lookaround syntax](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)?

Comment: does javascript's regex has this?

Comment: I don't know. Never worked with js. But most languages have added support.

Comment: It seems it doesn't support lookbehind, a workaround like you suggested: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript